# How to push a website to bitbucket

Tags: cygwin, bitbucket

I have website already developed locally that I want to share with other developers. 
I have created an account on Bitbucket and looking for a way to push and make my website available to others. 
Any idea? Sorry I'm quite new in this. I am using

> Cygwin Terminal on Windows 7

. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a look to this tutorial:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Import+code+from+an+existing+project

The basic code is:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/your_git_path.git
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: I am having the following error: `src refspec master does not math any`. Please any idea? thanks

Comment: please post the commands you ran. It happens when the url (ssh://blabla.git) is wrong. Also give a check to your bitbucket console it should give you the exact commands that should be run

Comment: Never mind. Thanks for the tip. I had to commit first before pushing.